# Printing substrings using recursion(void method)

Tags: java, recursion

I wanted to print the substrings in the following order :-
 “”, “d”, “c”, “cd”, “b”, “bd”, “bc”, “bcd”, “a”, “ad”, “ac”, “acd”, “ab”, “abd”, “abc”, “abcd”

I made a code which will get the first character of the strings and then the subsequent substring from the enxt character and will then call itself.
This process will go on until string is empty. Then I start joining the string and character to form the series.
I made the following code but it does not give the correct results for last few formations.
What am I doing wrong here?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrintSubstringsWithVoid {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scn =new Scanner(System.in);
        String str=scn.nextLine();
        printSub(str,'\0');
    }
    public static void printSub(String str,char ch1){

        if (str.length()==0){
            StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(ch1);
            System.out.println(sb.toString()+"");
            return;
        }
        char ch=str.charAt(0);
        String st=str.substring(1);
        printSub(st,ch1);
        StringBuilder sb1=new StringBuilder();
        if (st.length()<=1){
            sb1.append(ch);
            StringBuilder sb2=new StringBuilder();
            sb2.append(ch1);
            String stt=sb2.toString()+sb1.toString();
            System.out.println(stt);

            String st1=sb2.toString()+sb1.toString()+st;
            if (st.length()!=0) {
                System.out.println(st1);
            }
        }else{

            printSub(st,ch);
        }

    }
}
```

These are my results:-
d
c
cd
b
bd
bc
bcd
a
ad
ac
acd
b
bd
bc
bcd

Here for the last 4 formations 'a' is missing

Comment: So your program only output the  maximum last three character for each string . I failed to understand your program . but if you want then i can give you a another solution.

Comment: @mahbubcseju
Yes if you can help me with the solution it would be of great help.

Comment: Please have a look at the answer. And if it solves your problem then mark it as accepted and also up vote it . Thanks

Comment: @mahbubcseju As I have mentioned in the question I needed a solution which can print the result in the funtion itself. We have to use VOID in the function, without returning the ArrayList.
I was able to code it using return type as ArrayList but using VOID it is difficult.

Comment: @mahbubcseju the last solution you uploaded (Void Method) did work perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple like you have a string "abcd". So if you know the answer of "bcd" then the answer of "abcd" will be answer of "bcd" plus  the strings by adding 'a' with all the results of "bcd".

For example , 
The result of "bcd" is: `d, c, cd, b, bd, bc, bcd,`
So result of "abcd" will be : `d, c, cd, b, bd, bc, bcd, a, a+(d, c, cd, b, bd, bc, bcd)`

**So the solution  is :**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrintSubstrings {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scn =new Scanner(System.in);
        String str=scn.nextLine();
        ArrayList<String>ans=printSub(str);
        for(int i=0;i<ans.size();i++)
        {
            System.out.print(ans.get(i)+" ");
        }
    }
    public static ArrayList<String> printSub(String str) {

        if(str.length()==0)return new ArrayList<String>();

        ArrayList<String> fx=printSub(str.substring(1));

        int size=fx.size();
        fx.add(Character.toString(str.charAt(0)));
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            fx.add(str.charAt(0)+fx.get(i));
        }
        return fx;
    }
}
```

**Using void function:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class aa {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scn =new Scanner(System.in);
        String str=scn.nextLine();
       printSub(str,"");

    }
    public static void  printSub(String str,String pre) {

        if(str.length()==0){
           System.out.println(pre);
          return;
        }

         printSub(str.substring(1),pre);

         printSub(str.substring(1),pre+Character.toString(str.charAt(0)));

    }
}
```